# Windows Phone 8 Multiple Build From Same Solution

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have created a windows phone 8 application in VS2012. Now I have to take 2 two builds of same application (ex: "App1" and "App2") with some customization in the GUI. I have created two copies and renamed "Display Name", and "Assembly Name" and "Xap File Name" in project properties. But while deploying application (ex: "App1") to the phone the other (ex: "App2") is getting replaced.

**Please let me know how to create two customized applications from same code?**

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to deploy two applications side by side, they need to have a different product ID declared in the manifest (WPAppManifest.xml).

Comment: Thank You. It worked by adding new GUID, Product ID and Publisher ID

Answer (score 0):

I use a separate wp7 and wp8 solution. All the files as added as links as described [here](http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Maintaining_a_WP7_and_WP8_version_of_a_same_Silverlight_application).